# Using macros to generate argument list from __VA_ARGS__

Tags: python, c++, c++11, boost, macros

Just for a little background, this isn't a trivial exercise! I'm working with Boost.Python, and to avoid a lot of ugly boilerplate code, I'm using macros to wrap functions in Python wrapper classes to optionally call a Python override for the method if it exists.

I've boiled the conundrum down to it's simplest form, [here](http://ideone.com/rhMrPJ):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo() { cout << "foo" << endl; }
void bar(char, short, int) { cout <<"bar" << endl; }

#define DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER(return_type, name, ...)\
return_type name##_wrapper(/* macro expansion */)\
{\
    return name(/* macro expansion */);\
}\

DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER(void, foo)  // works!
//DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER(void, foo, char, short, int)  // knowledge insufficient

int main() {
    foo_wrapper();
    //bar_wrapper(0, 1, 2);
}
```

While this obviously works for `foo`, my goal is to have `DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER(void, foo, char, short, int)` generate a function wrapper that looks like this:

```
void bar_wrapper(char _1, short _2, int _3)
{
    return bar(_1, _2, _3);
}
```

I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction on how best to tackle this, as I really would like to master this kind of macro magic.

Any help is appreciated!

> NOTE: I'm compiling against MSVC C++11.

Comment: If `bar(char,short,int)` exists, what is the point of `bar_wrapper` being an exact alias for it?

Comment: Read the beginning of the post. This is a trivial example for a non-trivial implementation.

Comment: Maybe a less trivial example is needed. I fail to see the need to use macros.

Comment: A plane is going down and hundreds of people are going to die unless I use macros to generate this function wrapper! All joking aside, the triviality of the example provided in no way hinders the ability to understand the fundamental task I'm trying to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really need macros (I'm not too familiar with Boost.Python, but variadic templates and perfect forwarding are in the same vein as this, and much cleaner if they're applicable), you can use a couple of handy Boost.Preprocessor tools.

The catch is that the ellipsis at the end of your macro must have at least one argument passed in its place; it can't have zero. To combat this, you'll have to give up at least one parameter name somewhere along the way. I've chosen to make the macro choose one of two others based on whether it gets any parameter-related arguments to fill in that ellipsis.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

//generate "type _#"
#define PARAMS(z,n,data) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n,data) _##n

//The first variant: with parameters
//parameters: PARAMS(z,0,(char,short,int)), PARAMS(z,1,(char,short,int)), PARAMS(z,2,(char,short,int))
//call: _0, _1, _2

#define DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER_WITH_PARAMS(return_type, name, ...)\
return_type name##_wrapper(BOOST_PP_ENUM(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), PARAMS, (__VA_ARGS__)))\
{\
    return name(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), _));\
}

//The second variant: no parameters
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER_WITHOUT_PARAMS(return_type, name)\
return_type name##_wrapper()\
{\
    return name();\
}

//choose variant based on whether more than two arguments are passed
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER(...)\
    BOOST_PP_IF(\
        BOOST_PP_GREATER(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 2), \
        DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER_WITH_PARAMS,\
        DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER_WITHOUT_PARAMS\
    )(__VA_ARGS__)

//Clang output:
//void foo_wrapper( char _0 , short _1 , int _2){ return foo( _0 , _1 , _2);}
//int bar_wrapper(){ return bar();}
```

`BOOST_PP_ENUM` calls the given macro with increasing numbers, which we use in the `PARAMS` macro as both indices into the tuple of types (the passed in data) and in the name. It also puts commas between the expansions, but not after the last one. You can see the expansion of it in the code comments. `z` can be ignored if desired.

`BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS` saves the work of a separate macro and instead takes "a constant" to append the numbers to. It also puts commas between the expansions. We use underscores to end up with _0, _1, _2.

Comment: Looks like it will do the trick, though I need to work out some niggly compiler flags to enable calling `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE` on MSVC.

Comment: @cmbasnett, MSVC is pretty known for having a less-than-perfect preprocessor. As far as I know, most or all of Boost.PP has workarounds for it, though.

Comment: @cmbasnett, If worst comes to worst and `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS` isn't defined or something, then you can make the wrapper macro take the number of types its given and use `TUPLE_ELEM` with a size argument.

Comment: I've traced down why it's not defined: the `__EDG__` compiler flag needs to be undefined. Not sure really precisely what this is, but my skim reading has told me that it's fairly safe to `#undef` and that it's probably a bug in MSVC.

Comment: Hmm, does your `DEFINE_FUNCTION_WRAPPER` work with a no-arg function wrapper? I'm getting lots of `_0 not defined` errors when it tries to wrap those.

Comment: @cmbasnett, I've added some code to the answer to choose an implementation based on whether that ellipsis would have any arguments or have zero. I vaguely remember something about MSVC accepting zero arguments there, but I could be wrong and it evidently messes up the Boost utilities if it happens, which is reasonable considering it's not supposed to happen.